# yii2 : add IFNULL exception to Command

Tags: mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i've create command and it works fine but when I add  IFNull exception  it add a comma and i searched a lot there is no answer my code :

```
public function actionTotal($id)
{
     $query1 = new Query;
     $query1  ->select(' sum(patient_services.price) price ,
                sum( IFNULL(receipts.price,0)) receipts') 
              ->from('patient_services')
              ->leftJoin('receipts', 'patient_services.patient_id = receipts.patient_id')
              ->where('patient_services.patient_id=:id', array(':id'=>$id));      
     $command1 = $query1->createCommand();
     $price = $command1->queryAll();  
     echo Json::encode($price);
}
```

when i try it ... the select code have a comma and idon't know how to remove it

```
 SELECT sum(patient_services.price) price, sum( IFNULL(receipts.price, `0))` AS `receipts` FROM `patient_services` LEFT JOIN `receipts` ON patient_services.patient_id = receipts.patient_id WHERE patient_services.patient_id=2
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 0 as a second parameter for IFNULL function, so that if the value is null it will print 0, here is the example.

```
$query1->select(['sum(patient_services.price) price,
                sum( IFNULL(receipts.price,0)) receipts'])
```

Comment: I have just edited my ans, you need to put brackets [ ] in your select statement. Please see ans, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In you code

```
   $query1  ->select('sum(patient_services.price) price
                 ,sum( IFNULL(receipts.price,)) receipts')
                                            ^^ here is missing the value for ifnull 
                                               eg: ifnull(your_column, 0);
     ->from('patient_services')
     ->leftJoin('receipts', 'patient_services.patient_id = receipts.patient_id')
     ->where('patient_services.patient_id=:id', array(':id'=>$id));
```

then try

```
 $query1  ->select(' sum(patient_services.price) price ,
                    sum( IFNULL(receipts.price,0)) receipts') 
     ->from('patient_services')
     ->leftJoin('receipts', 'patient_services.patient_id = receipts.patient_id')
     ->where('patient_services.patient_id=:id', array(':id'=>$id));
```

looking at the strange result in your img

try using  this this notation and (remove also the two space between query1 and `->`

```
$query1->select(["sum(patient_services.price) AS price", 
     "sum( IFNULL(receipts.price,0)) AS receipts"]  )
```

And eventually try to clear runtime directory ..and flush the db cache

Comment: sorry i don't get it  :(

Comment: when i try it shows like this in inspect  ..  sum( IFNULL(receipts.price, ` 0 ) )`

Comment: when you try ... what's happen?

Comment: the zero comes between comma like this sum( IFNULL(receipts.price, ` 0 ) )`

Comment: I see two backtics  `   in your sum(....`0 ))`   try remove it  .. . i see this also in your original code . and i have removed .. .

Comment: i've add a picture to my question !

Comment: @NaeemMarzu   weird   .. after 20 days the same answer like mine buts posted after two hours became  the right answer ..

Comment: . I was new user .. I can do nothing .. and I got banned from this site ... my biggest problem is the.. English not my mother language !